Can an agency be liable for sending me home because they did not provide the correct uniform size?
I was urgently called to cover a shift in London today. Upon arrival, the supervisor gave me a jumpsuit, which clearly did not fit, causing me embarrassment. Despite this, he insisted I attempt to wear it, further adding to my humiliation. When I confirmed the uniform was indeed too small and requested an alternative, I was sent home because the client required staff in uniform. This situation not only resulted in lost work and academic opportunities but has also significantly impacted my mental health. I believe this treatment was inappropriate and am seeking advice on potential legal recourse.

Define too small.

This site does not provide legal advice on individual situations. For "advice on potential legal recourse" you need to hire a lawyer.

australia
It's your right (and the employer's obligation) to be paid the minimum hours per shift
What exactly that is depends on the particular award that applies. For example, for cleaners, it's 2 hours, and for retail workers, it's 3.
You were told to come, and you were told to leave.
